# How to import animation from directx .x file properly?

Tags: scripting, animation

I am almost finished with my directx importer with all mesh/bone/material, but the animation is just still bad. I would like to ask for help about how to get animation going properly, with using data collected from .x file.

I actually tried many variations, so I just could not tell what I tried already: nearly everything, really, I am sure I just missed something silly.

Here is a code I use at moment (and I do not ask you guys, to do it for me, but to point out the problem):

```
csontvaz_objektumkent.animation_data_create()
for animacio in animaciok:
    animacio_nev = animacio[0]
    uj_animacio = actions.new(animacio_nev);
    uj_animacio.use_fake_user = True;
    csontvaz_objektumkent.animation_data.action = uj_animacio
    max_matrix = animacio[2]
    for csontja in animacio[1]:
        csont = csontvaz_objektumkent.pose.bones[csontja[0]]
        if (csont == None):
            continue

        mi = len(csontja[1])
        li = max_matrix / mi
        i = 1

        for aktualis in range(len(csontja[1])):

            matrix_elozo = Matrix.Identity(4)
            if (aktualis != 0):
                matrix_elozo = csontja[1][aktualis -1]
            matrix_jelenlegi = csontja[1][aktualis]

            #nem jó: matrix_relativ = matrix_jelenlegi.inverted() - matrix_elozo
            (te,re,se) = matrix_elozo.decompose()
            (tj,rj,sj) = matrix_jelenlegi.decompose()
            rr = re.rotation_difference(rj)

            csont.rotation_quaternion = rr
            #csont.matrix = csontja[1][aktualis]

            bpy.context.scene.update()                       
            kulcs = i * 10
            csont.keyframe_insert('location',frame = kulcs)
            csont.keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion',frame = kulcs)
            csont.keyframe_insert('scale',frame = kulcs)
            i = i + li
```

I got an array of data collected, having bone names and the keyframes. The `csontvaz_objektumkent` is the armature object. I do all animations in `animaciok` and do fake_user so I do not lose it after saving as .blend file. I search for bones in `csontjai` and `csont` will be used as bone object found. I use several variables like `mi`, `li` and `i` to make sure, that every part is same length. Then I start with just one bone and here I left two variations in the code.

The first one uses the `matrix_elozo` and such: this will try to just use rotation quaternion. Takes the previous and current matrices and tries to have the bone rotated by the difference. The idea here is that I need only rotation, since the translation is just the length of the bone.

The second idea (with what I started) is that I just give the `.matrix` the value by the keyframe data.

None of them is working correctly. The best I got so far is like this:
[image]

and if you guessed that it looks bad, you guessed right.

**So my question would be that how can I do this right, having data from .X file?**

Comment: This is a really specific question, and likely nobody would know this answer off-hand unless they already wrote a `.X` importer before. Often you need to do some fairly cryptic matrix transformations to convert armature animations between files (see BVH importer for example). So I think you would likely be best off to learn more about Blender and .X treat bone transformations, and take a look at importers that have working armature importing. (C3D, BVH for eg).

Comment: Think this question is too narrow focus for blender.stackexchange. voted to close.